# Is there a better way to erase a line than echo " "?

Tags: bash

I am wanting to erase several (let's say 10) lines on the screen using bash.

I know this can be done by:

```
for x in `seq 1 10`; do
  echo "                                                    "
done
```

but there must be a better way.

Something like:

```
echo -n10 --blank
```

or

```
echo -n10 space(80)
```

or something similar.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$ printf "%80s" ""
```

to get 80 spaces, without a trailing newline. If you want to know how many spaces you need, $COLUMNS is probably want you want:

```
$ printf "%${COLUMNS}s" ""
```

will give you a blank line of the appropriate length even if you've resized your window. The "clear" command will clear the entire window, too.

Comment: Is there a way to repeat this - other than embedding it in a loop?

Comment: If you are worried about readability you could wrap the loop in a function

Comment: The preferred form for using a variable with field width: `printf '%*s' "$COLUMNS" ''` so that variable do not appear in the format string. `$COLUMNS` gets substituted for the asterisk.

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary to use `seq` in Bash:

```
for x in {1..10}
do
    dosomething
done
```

Let's say you want to clear 10 lines starting at the 8th line on the screen, you can use `tput` to move the cursor and do the clearing:

```
tput cup 8 0        # move the cursor to line 8, column 0
for x in {1..10}
do
    tput el          # clear to the end of the line
    tput cud1        # move the cursor down
done
tput cup 8 0        # go back to line 8 ready to output something there
```

See `man 5 terminfo` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `echo` still with terminal escapes:

```
ceol=$(tput el)
for x in `seq 10 -1 10`; do
   echo -n -e "\r${ceol}Counting $x"
   sleep 1
done
```

Or if you prefer:

```
echo -n -e "\033[1K\rCounting $x"
```

- `-n` do not output \n\r at end of line (so cursor stays at end of last character)
- `\r` return to start of line
- `${ceol}` clear to end of line (so comes after `\r`)
- `\033[1K` clear to start of line (so comes before `\r`)

Nb. made it count backwards to prove that the line is cleared; i.e. when printing 9, it shows that the 0 from 10 has been cleared.

Comment: PS. [ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) a useful reference

Comment: Note that you have to define `ceol` (or at least I had to): `ceol=$(tput el)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
for x in $(seq 10); do
  tput cup ($x)-1 0
  tput el                                               
done
```