# Bash output text formatting from loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, echo

I'm just trying to clean up some output from a one-liner script I run to check for file existence. To test I'm using 2 different terminals open on the same directory and running a continous "while true loop" to check if file exists and and if statement to output a message conditionally while having the other terminal generate and remove the test file for the test.

terminal-1
`dir: $ rm file ; sleep 10 ; touch file`

terminal-2
`dir: $ while true ; do if [[ -e $file ]] ; then echo -e "\e[1;32m FILE EXISTS\e[0m" ; break ;  else echo -en "\e[1;31m FILE DOES NOT EXIST YET\e[0m\r" ; fi ; done`

What ends up happening is I get the output I want in the else condition as "FILE DOES NOT EXIST" right but when the "`FILE EXISTS`" message appears it overwrites the first but only to the length of the string so I'll get " `FILE EXISTSOT EXIST`"

ChatGPT has been unhelpful. Anyone got any tips? I'm using the `-n` on the 2nd echo and `\r` to keep it all on one line and manageable as output to terminal till I get my FILE EXISTS message. I want it all on the same line clean and using the same `-n` and `\r` on the first echo does not help.

Comment: Try adding 8 spaces after `FILE EXISTS` so they overwrite the end of  the previous message.

Comment: Try adding a `\e[2K` to the beginning of the file-exists echo (erases the current line on some terminals)

Comment: Instead of `while true; do if [[ -e $file ]]; ... break;`, you can write `while ! [[ -e $file ]]; do ...`

Comment: I think you have to look about [inotify library](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), using [inotifywait in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323901/27653)

Comment: Add `\e[K` before or after `\e[0m`.

Answer (score 0):

You never erase the line, so if you write a shorter text over a longer one, part of the old text stays visible.

You could do a

```
tput el
```

(`el`= *Clear from the cursor to the end of the line*) before printing the new text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` instead of `echo -en` because the former is standard and not the later.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

file=$1

while :; do
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    printf '\e[1;32mFILE EXISTS\e[0m\e[K\n'
    break
  else
    sleep .2
    printf '\e[1;31mFILE DOES NOT EXIST YET\e[0m\r'
  fi
done
```

Also, using `inotifywait` may turn out to be a saner option to watch for a file creation event.

Down there, the loop only runs for each create event, and so is not busy loading the CPU probing for a file to materialize.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

filePath=$1
baseDir=${filePath%/*}
[ "$baseDir" = "$filePath" ] && baseDir=./

while
  ! [ -e "$filePath" ] && 
  printf '\r\e[1;31mFILE DOES NOT EXIST YET\e[0m'
do
  inotifywait -qqe create "$baseDir"
done

printf '\r\e[1;32mFILE EXISTS\e[0m\e[K\n'
```

Comment: By adding `\e[K` before your line, you make them *flash*. You would get nicer effect if you clear only after your print: `printf '\e[1;32mFILE EXISTS\e[0m\e[K\n'`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub modified with your suggestion and added `inotifywait`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using:

```
printf "\r\e[K\e[1;32m%-*s\e[0m\n" "${COLUMNS}" 'FILE EXIST'
```

So in combination this would create the following script:

```
printf '\e[1;31mFILE DOES NOT EXIST YET\e[0m'
while ! [ -e "$file" ]: do sleep 1; done
printf "\r\e[K\e[1;32m%-*s\e[0m\n" "${COLUMNS}" 'FILE EXIST'
```

Here we avoid continuously writing the same line

Note; be aware that `\r` does not remove a line, it just performs a carage return. If you redirect the output to a file, the original data will still be there.

Details here: [Is there a better way to erase a line than echo " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809868/is-there-a-better-way-to-erase-a-line-than-echo)